# Toggle button to enable/disable images in webview

Tags: android, button, toggle

how do i enable or disable the loading of images in a webview using a toggle button? i have used this code but the images are enabled forever.

```
   toggle=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglbtn1);
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(toggle.isChecked())
              {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The state is changed to on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);// Enable Image
                // Loading


              }
                else
                {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The state is changed to off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);// Enable Image
                    // Loading

                }
                 }
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to implement toggle button in android,

layout xml,

```
<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/leave_toggle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_toggle"
                android:minHeight="1dp"
                android:minWidth="1dp"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />
```

Drawable xml,
@drawable/custom_toggle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/notification_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/notification_off" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

notification_on and notification_off are the images

Inside activity,

```
private ToggleButton getToggleButton(int id) {
        return (ToggleButton) findViewById(id);
    }
```

Set oncheckedchagelistener to the toggle button, it will notify when user enable or disable the button with ischecked

```
 getToggleButton(R.id.leave_toggle).setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                    new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            if(isChecked)
                           {
                            // enabled
                             }else
                                  {
                           //disabled
                                  }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: don't know how to implement this, can you assist? or edit the code instead?